# Vlookup function with 2 possible lookupvalue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm having some trouble finishing my VLOOKUP function.

**My function:**

```
=IFERROR((VLOOKUP($E5,'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$7:$G$1048576,2,FALSE)), "Removed")
```

--> This function works, but not for values with wildcard characters, 
in my table array, there are some numerical values with asterisks at the end. For these special numbers, it returns an error (or removed in this case).

**Example of table array:**

```
1.1
1.2
1.3*
1.4
1.5*
```

--> How do I adjust the VLOOKUP to account for regular numbers, and numbers with asterisks (wildcard character)?

--> **Note** I cannot remove the asterisks from the other workbook, those must stay there

--> I want it to find either of the two values (the one with asterisk, or the one without)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have anything like `1.3.1` ? The asterisk is actually a wildcard character. Can you change it to something like ¹ ?

Comment: Is it always just 1 decimal? If so, you can try a `left(cell,3)`.

Comment: how about `=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E5,'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$7:$G$1048576,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP($E5&"*",'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$7:$G$1048576,2,FALSE)), "Removed")`?

Comment: @Jeeped Unfortunately I can't change the asterisk, but I only have 1 decimal on my numbers, so 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 14.1, etc.

Comment: @DirkReichel No this does not work, let me troubleshoot and evaluate, and see where it went wrong

Comment: @findwindow but what if we have 14.1* , that's 5 characters, so this wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe the *no formula-copy-from-comment*-bug... tested it locally and it worked... will check it again... pls check the first `FALSE`... there are *invisible* sybols in front of it :/

Comment: @DirkReichel It worked! I'm not sure what I copied wrong the first time, but the I erased everything and copied it again and it worked! Thank you so much! Unique use of the IFERROR function, never thought of using it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for having an acceptable answer:

You can simply check for the value without the `*` and if that leads to an error, auto-add it like:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E5,'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$7:$G$1048576,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP($E5&"*",'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$7:$G$1048576,2,FALSE)),"Removed")
```

Answer (score 1):

try converting the lookup value by a function that returns either numeric and character values, like this:

```
=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VALUE($E5);$E5),'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$7:$G$1048576,2,FALSE)), "Removed")
```

P.S.: Sorry my english

Comment: Good catch on the text-that-looks-like-a-number vs. true numbers thing. I think you left a semicolon in there.

Comment: Maybe i got the OP wrong... but the `*`'s are in the `[Example.xlsx]`-table and this functions won't help at all... I think he want to input `1.3` and get the output from the `1.3*`-row (cus there is no `1.3`)

Comment: @DirkReichel Yes Dirk is correct, this formula unfortunately does not work. Since the 1.3* is in the other workbook. This formula just checks if the current workbook cell is a value or not. But I think you are on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post the answer for anyone that didn't find it in the comments.

**--> Thank you to Dirk Reichel for the answer.**

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($E5,'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!   
 $F$7:$G$1048576,2,‌​FALSE),VLOOKUP($E5&"*",'C:\Users\[Example.xlsx]Sheet1'!
 $F$7:$G$1048576,2,FALSE)), "Removed")
```

The first VLOOKUP looks through to see if there is a value without and asterisk (*), then if there isn't a value, it will go to the value if the first VLOOKUP is incorrect. This leads you to the second value which is another VLOOKUP. The second VLOOKUP searches for a value ending with an asterisk. If it still doesn't find a value, then it will spew out "Removed" as demonstrated by the second IFERROR function.